# Flutter: From Stateless Widget to Stateful Widget with MaterialPageRoute

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Detail Page as a `StatelessWidget`. I have a `listview` in my Feed.dart. With click on an Listview Element to you get to the Detail Page. Now I want to convert the Detail Stateless in a Stateful, but in my feed MaterialPageRoute is now the Error, that the named Parameter shop is not defined. How do i fix the Error?

Detail as Stateless

```
    class Detail extends StatelessWidget {

  final Shop shop;
  Detail({ this.shop });

  var top = 0.0;

  int segmentedControlGroupValue = 0;
  final Map<int, Widget> myTabs = const <int, Widget>{
    0: Text("Item 1"),
    1: Text("Item 2")
  };
```

my Detail as a Stateful Widget

```
class Detail extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
  _DetailState createState() => _DetailState(Shop());
}


class _DetailState extends State<Detail> {

  final Shop shop;
  _DetailState(this.shop);


  var top = 0.0;
```

and my feed

```
class ShopTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final Shop shop;
  ShopTile({ this.shop });

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
      child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Detail(shop: shop)),
        );
      },
```

It says the first shop is no longer defined in detail. Therefore there is an error. When it was a stateless widget, it all still worked. Can you please help me where the error is?

Answer (score 2):

You should put the constructor in `Detail` class not in `_DetailState` :

```
class Detail extends StatefulWidget {
  final Shop shop;
  Detail({ this.shop });

   @override
  _DetailState createState() => _DetailState(Shop());
}


class _DetailState extends State<Detail> {

  var top = 0.0;
  Shop shopValue; 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // access the property 'shop' using 'widget.shop' 
    shopValue = widget.shop
  }
}
```

Comment: I cant change it like that. the widget.shop get this error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers. And the Shop in _DetailState(Shop()); get this error -> Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Ashok's solution is right.  On your feed needs onTap needs to be changed

```
onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Detail(shop: widget[index])),
    );
  },
```